# Android: implement sensormanager in a class

Tags: android, sensormanager

I'm building an android application that uses the accelerometer. I create a class named "SensorManager". But i cant get the default sensor:

Picture: ftp://horssen.net:60/Programming1.png

When i create a new project with the same code, it works:

Picture: ftp://horssen.net:60/Programming2.png

I cant understand why the code in my own class isn't working.

Comment: please post the snippet of code with the error you get

Comment: Change your activity name, That's the problem. You are using in-bulit name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your activity as `SensorManager` which is wrong because there is already a [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) Class in SDK

Try re-naming your activity.